# Как установить предыдущую версию браузера chromium на ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Я хочу установить предыдущую версию chromium-browser (мне нужна любая до 98). Я пытался делать это такой командой `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser=80.0.3987.163` но получаю

```
Версия «80.0.3987.163» для «chromium-browser» не найдена
```

В поисковике я пробовал искать предыдущие версию, но он ничего не находит, подскажите пожалуйста как найти и установить старую версию chromium?

Comment: Чё `aptitude versions chromium-browser` говорит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Официальный способ описан тут https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium/

Переходишь по ссылке https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/

Tools Version Information вводишь нужную версию .

в ответе ищи `Branch Base Position: 722274`

В снапшотах ищи цифру близкую к этой. Для разных ОС номер может быть +- немного отличаться.

Билд 97 версии найдешь тут: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/938554/

[80ый тут](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/722276/)

Качаешь chrome-linux.zip, распаковываешь  и  запускаешь файл `chrome`

Comment: Не подскажете как вы ориентируетесь на сайте, т.е как понять что папка с названием 938554 это 97 версия?

Comment: в первой ссылке ж написанно

Comment: @Dima добавил в ответ

Answer (score 1):

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/tags/96.0.4664.85
качаешь репу и устанавливаешь Readme.md прочти